# Remote WSUS administration console connection error

Tags: remote, wsus

I'm using the remote WSUS console from my computer on one subnet to connect to two different WSUS servers on two different subnets. I've managed to connect to one ok but the second one gives me the following error:

Cannot connect to 'ServerName'. The server may be using another port or different Secure Sockets Layer setting.

The WSUS server is running on port 80 and can connect to this via telnet so a little stumped as to why this isn't connecting. Connection traffic has been confirmed by the Firewall provider upstream so is getting through.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you have defined as a "server aka ServerName" under gpo?

Comment: Hi Michal, Do you mean set as the intranet update service for detecting updates? If so it's set as http://servername. This is in the same format as the subnet that is letting me connect.

Comment: Does this WSUS serve use the default website or the custom website? If using the custom website (which is the default in later versions of WSUS) then the ports are 8530/8531, not 80/443.

Comment: No, this is using the default website and as mentioned, running on port 80 as specified in the WSUS console under the connection heading. I'm able to download iuident.cab from a web browser when browsing to http://ServerIP/iuident.cab so communication appears to be working and as mentioned, can telnet to this also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was simply down to permissions. I found this answer on another post I had previous seen before posting this question but thought I'd already tried this.

[Using WSUS Admin Console from outside domain](https://serverfault.com/questions/443782/using-wsus-admin-console-from-outside-domain?rq=1) - Zac Garrett's post about running as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Map a drive to the server(s) you need to connect to using an account created and given WSUS Admin access. Then connect to the WSUS server with the Admin console.